# Reg Ex to match data between 3rd set of quotes with a number 8, 9 or 10

Tags: regex

I need to bookmark lines in Notepad++ where the number between the 3rd pair of double quotes is either an 8 ,9 or 10.

Example Match:
100013,"21","","8","4","20071101","20071031",01/11/2007,31/10/2007,21,0,8,4

Example Non-Match
100013,"21","31","","4","20011201","20011130",01/12/2001,30/11/2001,21,31,0,4

TIA,

Simon

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may search for the following regular expression :

```
^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*){2}"([89]|10)"
```

It matches the first two quotes-enclosed values from the beginning of the line, followed by a third that must be either "8", "9" or "10".

---

Detailed explanation :

```
^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*){2}"([89]|10)"

^                                    from the start of the line
 [^"]*                               match any non-quote character
      (            ){2}              match two occurrences of :
       "[^"]*"                         a quote-enclosed value
              [^"]*                    that can be followed by characters other than "
                       "         "   then match a quote-enclosed value
                        ([89]|10)    which is either one of 8 and 9, or 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not matching as I expected. Sample line below

100013,"21","","8","4","20071101","20071031",01/11/2007,31/10/2007,21,0,8,4

Comment: @sb5917 Ok, I assumed your lines would only contain quotes-enclosed values. `^[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*){2}"([89]|10)"` seems to work, can you check to make sure there isn't another problem?

Comment: Aaron - That's works as expected. Thank you very much.